# How we move a label when mouse click on it and when mouse key up then stop moving inside a group box

Tags: c#, windows

When is try with code, there appear two label and when move, screen become white from where they move. I want single label move with mouse move.

```
bool mDown = false;
private void label13_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mDown)
    {
        label13.Location = e.Location;
    }
}
private void label13_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = true;
}
private void label13_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = false;
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What is not working with your code right now?

Comment: Problem is that. Label not moving with mouse moving. If you have any idea then please share why label position not coming correct. **Label must move with mouse when mouse click and hold. and when mouse up then stop moving**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e.Location gives you a mouse position relative to the control that is being clicked. So to fix that, instead of

```
   label13.Location = e.Location;
```

use

```
   var pos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
   label13.Location = new Point(pos.X - offset.X, pos.Y - offset.Y);`
```

Create the offset variable as a property of the form (type Point) and initialize it on the mouse down event:

```
offset = e.Location;
```

Comment: Y co-ordinate goes 40 pixel down to the mouse position when it move. Can you check what is the problem in your code.

Comment: It works for me, but you can try to narrow the problem down by removing the offset subtraction (its not really mandatory for this to work) and see if it helps.